# require('config') loaded nothing in debug

Tags: node.js, node-config

My nodejs app `config = require('config')` (3.0.1) returns nothing in debug. Here is the console output:

```
 config: 
 Config {}
```

`NODE_ENV` is only defined in development.json and loading in development has no problem.

Here is the files under ./config:

[image]

What could cause the config module failed to load in debug?

Comment: You need an index.js in the config directory. Do  you want an exemple of config dir ?

Comment: `Julien TASSIN`, an example would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: oh, sorry my bad I did not see that you used `node-config`, I thought you were using pure nodejs. I don't know this lib :/

Answer (score 1):

The config filenames need to be tied to the NODE_ENV or NODE_CONFIG_ENV you're setting when you run your app. (https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files#file-load-order)

You don't set NODE_ENV in the config files themselves.

So for example (assuming the command to run your app is `npm start`):

`NODE_CONFIG_ENV=foo npm start`

^ This would first load all of the config properties in `default.json`, then override them with any properties you set in `foo.json`. If you wanted to add a `local.json`, those properties would be a final override.

I believe it defaults to assuming your env is "development", and I'm guessing your default.json is empty.

Comment: All setting goes to the default.json as well. The issue is the the config is loaded successfully in normal development (for ex, when node index.js) but not in debug with VS code. I posted on VS code to find out if this is something related to the IDE.